# What type of Test should I conduct?

Tags: anova, multivariate-analysis, descriptive-statistics, manova

The same participants are exposed to two different screen sizes 27" (stimulus A) and screen size 9.7" (stimulus B). Independent var is "screen" with two levels - sizes. After exposure to stimulus A, they fill two questionnaires to answer dependent variables Y1 and Y2. After that, they are exposed to stimulus B, and asked to fill the same above questionnaires to respond to the same dependent var Y1 and Y2.

Y1: Attention
Y2: Endurability

I want to compare each set of their responses (dependent var) of each stimulus. What kind of ANOVA test should I conduct?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have just one independent variable (screen), because the subject can be seen as replicas of the same experiment.

If screen sizes can be just 27" and 9.7", then screen is a fixed effect. If 27" and 9.7" are just two sizes among a larger set of available sizes and they have been used in the experiment to check if screen size affects your dependent variable, then it's a random effect.

Then, for each variable Y1 and Y2 you can run an ANOVA analysis with one (fixed or random) effect.

If you were interested in how the independent variables affect the relation between the dependent variables, then [MANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_analysis_of_variance) could be a better choice than two separated a ANOVAs.

Comment: Hi, Is the procedure the same for a fixed and random effects if I want to pursue a MANOVA? The independent var is screen size (with level: desktop: (27" and mobile: 9.7"). Each participant from the sample was randomly assigned  to each treatment to counter order effects. Since I wanted to examine the effect of each screen size on Y1 and Y2, I thought a regression analysis would be appropriate. With MANOVA, we compare the means of the different dependent var to check if there is any significant difference among the "groups." How do we study the effect? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you